# css3 scale transform / preserve image quality

Tags: css, transform, scale

Let's say a 2000x2000px pixel image is initially displayed at a size that is 10 times lower, meaning 200x200px

If transformed through a CSS3 `scale(10)` here method, it will sure works fine, bu it'll also look very blurry, even if the image is initially displayable at such a size

Is there a way to get the initial image size back though this kind of transform ? Meaning displaying the "original" sizes image through a transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the image in a container, and scale the container. No need for transforms in this case

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div:hover {
    width: 2000px;
    height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://www.solarviews.com/raw/earth/bluemarblewest.jpg" width="2048" height="2048"></div>
```

Reusing the image from Timo D ... Too lazy to search for another one :-)

Comment: You mean using three just for that ? I don't think it is worth it .. Unless there is something in your requirements that I don't know. You should be able to get a good solution using pure HTML/CSS

Comment: it is not only that. As I'm using the css3Drenderer, it is related : camera.z 'zooms' on the image (equivalently in CSS, its a transform:scale(x) of the image)

Answer (score 2):

You could try and do the scaling the other way around.

So, in the regular state, you downscale the image to 200x200 with `transform: scale(0.1)` and when you want it to enlarge, just set it to `scale(1)`. That way you shouldnt experience any blurriness.

Checkout this j[sFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rwhw2km/).

Comment: Ah! That's would be the thing to do if it was possible (i'm not going to explain it all here why but rather would be 200% happy to find a solution)

Comment: okay sure. could you provide an image where you experience the issues so I can test it for myself?