# Move element without enlarging surround elements

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

This is going to come across as a potentially dumb question, but I'm feeling like [this](https://i.imgur.com/Q3cUg29.gif) right now.

I want to resize and move around this ampersand, but whenever I do anything, it adjusts everything around it.

[image]

Basically, I need it larger and positioned centered next to the logo, but it keeps increasing the overall size of the jumbotron and page which I don't want. To sum it up, I need the larger ampersand from the first image to be in the jumobtron size from this second image.

[image]

Below is the relevant code.

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-11">
   <img src="~/Images/Logo.png" id="CDPHPlogo" />
    <span class="ampersand">&</span>
    <span>Your Tabacco-Free Resource</span>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-1">
   <img src="~/Images/MenuButton.png" id="menuButton" />
</div>
<div class="jumbotron" id="homejumbo">
   <div class="container">      
     <h2></h2>       
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menuButton 
  {
   padding-top: 15px;
  }

 #CDPHPlogo 
   {
   }

.ampersand 
 {
  font-size: 140pt;
  color: white;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the CSS Attribute `transform:;` as it will not affect other elements on the page. Here a nice little guide. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform/

Say you want to make it larger, you could use:

```
.ampersand {
  font-size: 140px;
  color: white; 
  transfrom: scale(1.25,1.25);
}
```

This will increase the size by 25%. Use `transform: translate();` to move the element around vertically or horizontally. You may need to use something like `transform: scale(1.5,1.5) translateY(50px);` to move a scale the element and position it where you want it.

Comment: This worked great! I completely blanked on Transform! Now, is there a way to scale it without losing resolution, or would it best to use a much larger image and then just scale it down?

Comment: @M.Straw. This might help, try placing the image in a container and then scale the container, not the image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556426/css3-scale-transform-preserve-image-quality

Comment: Transform, for the most part is working. However when I still try to increase font sizes it increases the size of the jumbotron it's in. Can I keep the jumbotron at a fixed size?

Comment: Have you tried applying `max-height` to the jumbotron?